# Making a symlink for a bin file and renaming it to "readme" (w/o extension) gives it text file properties

Tags: 14.04, symbolic-link, extension, binary

When I create a symlink for a bin file(on Ubuntu 14.04 or 16.04) and rename it "readme", it shows as a link to text file. Also, when i checked the properties of this file, it says "Link to text/document". The strange thing is that the icon also changes to that of a text file from that of a bin file. Moreover, only when I change the filename to "readme" does that happen. If i rename the link to, say, "abc", it shows as a link to bin file with a bin icon.

Why is that?

Comment: Maybe these articles will help: [Wikipedia: Filename extension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filename_extension) and [TechTerms: File Extension](https://techterms.com/definition/fileextension).

Comment: @SpasSpasov The thing is that I don't add an extension. I simply name it 'readme' and it changes it's icon and properties. Had I added a .txt extension, this behavior is understandable. But without an extension, I expect it to remain a bin file symlink with bin properties.

Comment: Try renaming to `authors` and tell me if still has the text character...

Comment: I realised what you mean :)

Comment: File a bug, there is no reason for a file manager to make silly assumptions about the type of a file.  The confusion does not exist when using the file command in a terminal.

Comment: @ubfan1 I totally agree. Such assumptions can definitely be misleading. Maybe I should file a bug as you said. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

## File Naming in Linux

> Excepts:
>
> A relatively small number of file names on a system consist only of upper case characters, such as README, INSTALL, NEWS and AUTHORS. They are usually plain text files that come bundled with programs and are for documentation purposes.

There are files that are expected to be of a certain nature based on *Linux File Naming Convention*, these include names like `README, AUTHOR, THANKS, INSTALL, CHANGELOG, NEWS` e.t.c. I believe Ubuntu is *enforcing* those conventions and naming any file with those names will automatically give them certain properties following Linux Standards and conventions.

So its best to avoid naming files with those types of names. Please also look at `man file` to how that tool determines file types. You will find it a good read.

Source:

[File Naming Conventions in Linux](http://www.linfo.org/file_name.html)

[README](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/README)

Comment: This is what I sought. +1 :) But I've made few tests and I found an undetermined behaviour - see [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KKz82.png).

Comment: @SpasSpasov Ubuntu usually acts a bit off from the norm, perhaps its being enforced by his system. Wouldn't know... What version are you using?

Comment: @George Yes, I had witnessed the same behavior with install & changelog as well earlier. My concern is that one could use this nature of Linux to do malicious stuff. Imagine sending such a readme or authors file to someone, which is actually linked to a bin file. Since the file shows a text doc icon and says it's linked to a text document, more or less the victim would open it.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe it's automatically adding a .txt extension when you rename to "readme", not sure why it's only happening for that particular string though. Check your file manager settings to change this behavior if you don't want to hide file extensions.

Comment: Why should renaming add any file-extension? Also, "Maybe" is never a good formula to start an answer.